# Какой подход лучше использовать для обработки ошибок?

Tags: java, api, исключения, архитектура, scala

Для начала коротко расскажу, как я к этому пришел. Код писал на Scala, но в целом это актуально и для Java.

Размышляя о том, что исключения очень медленнные (по моим тестам в 20-30 раз медленнее обычного if), я начал искать альтернативные пути решения. Почти везде рекомендуют что-то вроде этого:

```
interface UserDao {
     Optional<User> find(long id);
}
```

Это очень логично, ведь пользователь может и не существовать с таким id.
Вот только поднимаемся на уровень выше:

```
 interface AuthService {
     Optional<User> auth(String login, String pass);
}
```

И здесь Optional уже не подойдет. Нет такого пользователя, а почему? Логин неверный или пароль? А если мы поднимемся еще на уровень выше, то появляются еще больше, например банально ошибки парсинга, когда мы передали букву, а нужно было цифру.

В Scala есть еще и монада Try, а можно еще и свой тип похожий сделать. И все это работает очень быстро и хорошо, только целая куча вызовов map выглядит каким то костылем, к тому же делает абсолютно тоже самое что и обычная обработка исключений.

Поизучав тему с исключениями, я создал тип исключения, в котором fillStackTrace включался и выключался переменной среды. И скорость работы стала сравнима со скростью обычных .flatMap. Но я такого вообще нигде и никогда не видел.

Сосбтвенно, есть ли какой-то плюс-минус стандартный или просто распространненый подход к предоставлению в своём API подробных описаний того, что пошло не так?

Comment: Просто не изобретайте велосипед и воспользуйтесь готовым решением, например `Slf4j`

Comment: Я говорю не о логировании (причем тут оно вообще?). Я говорю о API. Например, мы пишем в адресной строке бразуера: getUserArticle?user=3&ariticle=7. И мы можем получить JSON либо со статьей, либо с описанием ошибки - NotANumber, NoSuchUser, NoSuchArticle, WrongToken, ServiceUnavailable и т.д.

Comment: Дайте я ревьювну "целую кучу map", где оно выглядит костылём.

Answer (score 3):

Цитата из 3-го издания Effective Java:

> An Optional is an object that has to be allocated and initialized, and reading the value out of the optional requires an extra indirection. This makes 
>   optionals inappropriate for use in some performance-critical situations. 
>   Whether a particular method falls into this category can only be determined by careful measurement

и ещё одна оттуда же:

> You should, however, be aware that there are real performance consequences 
>   associated with returning optionals; for performance-critical methods, it may be better to return a null or throw an exception.

В общем, выигрыша в перформансе вы, используя опшионалы, точно не получите.
Да и так ли это критично в вашем конкретном случае? Вряд ли.

Optional - это своего рода более удобный аналог checked exception - вы заставляете пользователя своего апи соответствующим образом его обрабатывать, принимать разные шаги в зависимости от того, Optional пришёл пустой или нет. Поэтому можно использовать его там, где бы вы использовали checked exception.

А вообще обработка исключений - довольно холиварная тема. Лично я принадлежу к лагерю тех, кто не использует checked exception в своём апи и создаёт кастомные рантайм-эксепшены на каждый конкретный случай. Например:

```
public User find(long id) {
   User user = someMethodTofindUserInDb();
   if (user == null)
    throw new UserNotFoundException(String.format("пользователь с id=%d не найден", id));

   return user;
}

public class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public UserNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Используя runtime exceptions, вы даёте пользователям апи самим решать, на каком уровне они хотят его обрабатывать.

И, кстати, я бы не подсказывал пользователю, что именно он неправильно ввёл - пароль или логин, ибо нечего подбором заниматься). А кинул бы какую-нибудь WrongUsernameOrPasswordException...

Comment: Да, мне тоже очень нравится подход с unchecked exceptions. С login/pass был лишь пример, там может быть что угодно. Но вот с Optional спорный момент... С одной стороны мы даже проиграем относительно Exception, потому что в случае когда все ок, у нас нужно будет создавать дополнительный объект. Но в случае когда все плохо и нужно бросать Exception у нас наблюдаются дикие тормоза на заполнение стека, причем мои измерения - замедление в 20-30 раз это еще очень скромно по сравнению с тем что я видел у ребят в статьях. Вообще получается можно задудосить сервер просто посылая неверный ID.

Comment: @Uraty обрабатывать Optional всё равно придётся. А если он пустой? Что будете делать? Если кидать эксепшен, то лучше кидать его сразу с нижнего уровня и ловить там, где это будет удобно. А что до замедления... Работаю в большом проекте, пилим довольно нагруженное энтерпрайзное приложение и спокойно кидаем эксепшены в исключительных ситуациях. По-моему, зацикливаться на этом не стоит. У вас есть такие вещи, как, например, раундтрипы к БД - вот где bottleneck будет, скорее всего. Не надо только пользоваться эксепшенами для управления потоком приложения, и всё будет ок.

Answer (score 2):

Подход к обработке исключений зависит от требований задачи.

И так есть функция, что она может вернуть:

1. То что вы искали. Например юзера.
2. То что вы искали не найдено. Возвращаем например `None`.
3. То что вы искали не найдено, и нужно сформировать сообщение на этом уровне, но стек-трейс вам НЕ нужен. Например, "Имя пользователя *Олег* слишком короткое".
4. Произошло что-то о чём просто одним сообщением не передать и нужен ещё стек-трейс.

Ок, возможных вариантов ответа функции несколько, но ответ будет один. Понятней всего - это можно было бы изобразить с помощью Union Type, вот так:

1. `User`
2. `User | Null`
3. `User | String`
4. `User | Exception`

Так, конечно, наглядно, но сейчас в языке Union Type нету, зато есть монады с удобными методами и синтаксисом работы с ними:

1. `User`
2. `Option[User]`
3. `Either[String, User]`
4. `Try[User]`.

Работать с монадами довольно удобно с помощью *for-comprehension*:

```
def getUserFriends(userId: Int): List[User] = for {
  user      <- findUser(userId).toList
  friendId  <- user.friends
  friend    <- findUser(friendId)
} yield friend

case class User(id: Int, friends: List[Int])

def findUser(userId: Int): Option[User] = ???
```

Монады выше работают с двумя вариантами ответа, как на счёт трёх? Вкладываем один в другой - `Try[Option[User]]`. Cкажем, мы ищем юзера в базе данных:

1. Мы его нашли - `Success(Some(User("John")))`
2. Не нашли - `Success(None)`
3. Ошибка соединения - `Failure(new Exception("Time out")`

Тут уже возникает другая проблема, даже с *for-comprehension* работать с вложенными монадами становится не удобно - для этого есть специальные монады-трансформеры. Расписывать про них тут я, пожалуй, не буду.

---

Согласен с @fromSPb по этой теме:

> Optional - это своего рода более удобный аналог checked exception.

И не согласен с этим:

> В общем, выигрыша в перформансе вы, используя опшионалы, точно не получите.

Собственно измерения автора вопроса опровергают утверджение из цитаты.

---

В подавляющем большинстве моих проектов в кидании исключений не было необходимости.

Comment: утверждение об отсутсвии выигрыша в перформансе базируется на на другой цитате - той, которая из Effective Java, которая рекомендует не использовать Optional там, где важен этот самый перформанс. Как правильно заметил Uraty, мы каждый раз создаём лишний объект, + есть некоторый оверхед на чтение значения из него, и он имеется на постоянной основе. А исключительные ситуации - они ведь недаром исключительными называются, не постоянно случаются. И значительно снизить их количество может, например, грамотная валидация входных данных.